# Multiple Themes Plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I published WordPress website and the website was working until yesterday when I visited it I found an error but after search I found that the problem with plugin called Multiple Theme which I used in my website to set the home page a different theme from the active theme when I checked the theme settings i found that Warning
Deprecated: Function unregister_setting was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 4.7.0! $sanitize_callback is deprecated. The callback from register_setting() is used instead. in /home/rasans/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6031
I tried to deactivate the plugin and the website worked but with the active theme only.
So how can I solve this problem because I need this plugin to use the both themes.
Edit
If someone knows alternative plugin i will be thankful to know it

Comment: Ask plugin dev for update / fix. Or just wait for an update ..

Comment: the support page isn't working

Comment: Then revert the WP version and wait for update then update your WP core. Or find alternative plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, solved by downloading fresh wp installation, then copy all files from wp-includes(new) to server wp-includes.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35491516)